# need a help for change the root chroot /mnt/sysimage in rescue mode

Tags: chroot

my grub file corrupted and entered to rescue mode. after at shell prompt, unable to change chroot /mnt/sysimage.
 I tried to ln -s /bin/bash /mnt/sysimage/bin/sh but not changed, copies some libraries from /lib64 to root..still getting an error chroot:failed torun a command:/bin/bash:no such file or directory.

can someone please insight into this problem
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome.  First, please avoid posting screenshots; it's preferable to just describe the problem.  Second, does `/mnt/sysimage/bin/bash` exist?

Comment: That appears to be the Anaconda installation environment which would not mount your existing disks by default.  You seem to be looking for the RedHat Rescue Environment which would have attempted to mount your existing disks at `/mnt/sysimage`.  If you successfully installed RedHat, the rescue environment should be a choosable boot option.  If you are not getting proper boot options, is your machine booting from the correct device?